# How to initialize codeigniter session data?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the codeigniter session class (autoload). How can I set initialize values? I need this because I want to initialize the default language.

Best regards ...

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I know the user guide. But where to set inital values of a session if I use it via autoload? I don't want to initialize them in each controller!

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand the question before.  I get what you want now.  You can use a hook to do that.  Give me a sec to write up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load initialize data into your session, you can use [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html).

You can use a `post_controller_constructor` hook (in the `pre_controller` hook, the session may not loaded yet).

Open up `config/hooks.php` and add this:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                                'class'    => 'SessionData',
                                'function' => 'initializeData',
                                'filename' => 'SessionData.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array()
                                );
```

And then in the `hooks` folder make a file called `SessionData.php` containing the following:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class SessionData{
    var $CI;

    function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function initializeData() {
          // This function will run after the constructor for the controller is ran
          // Set any initial values here
          if(!$this->session->userdata('language')){
             $this->CI->session->set_userdata('language', 'English');
          }
    }
}
?>
```